# RESTful way to preallocate an ID

Tags: api, rest

For some reasons my application needs to have an API that flows like:

1. Client calls server to get ID for a new resource.
2. Then user spends a while filling out the forms for the resource.
3. Then user clicks save (or not...), and when he does the client saves by writing to `/myresource/{id}`

What is the RESTful way to design this?

How should the first call look like? On server side, it's a matter of generating an ID and returning it. It has side effects (increments sequence and thus "reserves space"), but it doesn't explicitly create a resource.

If I understand correctly, the 3rd call should be a PUT because it creates something with a known URI.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is:

- client `POST`s empty body to `/myresource/`
- server answers with status code `302 (Found)` with a `Location` response header set to `/myresource/newresourceid` (to indicate the ID / URI that should be used to create the resource)
- client `PUT`s the new resource to `/myresource/newresourceid` once the user is done filling the form.

Seems RESTful enough. ;)

Comment: It feels dirty, and doesn't seem to work. When server sends 302, browser always follows the redirect automatically. And it should, because that's what 302 is for.

Comment: Good point... Ajax request always follow the 3XX so you'll end up getting 404s.

Comment: Another thought (thinking out loud): what about exposing the new ID as a custom header on the collection endpoint:

- client performs HEAD (or POST?) on /myresource/?generateId=true
- server responds with empty body and header "X-New-Id: 12345" (or Location header with URL of new resource).

Custom headers aren't really elegant but this isn't a very standard REST operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested to see the other answers to this question as I imagine there's a lot of ways to do this.

If possible I would let your auto-incrementing ID in the database serve as your surrogate key and assign another field to be your *business identifier*. It could be something like a product code or a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).

With this in mind the client can now create the *ID* themselves which removes the need for step 1 at all. They would do a PUT to a url such as `/myresource/MLN5001` or `/myresource/3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301` to create the resource. If the ID is already in use return a [409 Conflict](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10) with the conflict in the response body. Otherwise return a [201 Created](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2) and include the URI to the resource in the response body and location header.

Comment: The thing is, more often than not there are numerous resources and there is not a way for users to control their numbers. If you create 100 orders a day (36,500 a year), you can't expect concurrent users to manually type in identifiers or invent unique values.

Comment: They are already typing in the orders, pick one of the fields that they are filling out and use that as your business identifier. Alternatively you can generate a GUID client side (risk of collision is negligible).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
GET /myresource/new-id
POST /myresource/{id}
```

Your walkthrough is pretty clear on the verb:

> 1. "to GET [an] ID for a new resource"

you could rename new-id to whatever you think makes it most clear. If you have multiple resources you need to do this for, it would probably be better to split out the generator into its own resource, such as

```
GET /id-generator/myresource
GET /id-generator/my-other-resource
```

If there are multiple cases, the user will quickly learn they need to hit id-generator to get their ID. If it's only one case, it's annoying for them to only have to use it infrequently.

I guess you could also do

```
GET /myresource-id-generator/next
```

which looks a little clearer, but then if you ever need another ID to be generated you have to make another resource to do it.

Comment: GET feels wrong because it will change with time, it has side effects, it's not idempotent...

Answer (score 0):

ID allocation is non-idempotent — two invokes of the allocation operation will get *different* IDs — so that should always be a POST. From that point on, the resource should conceptually exist. However, what I'd do at that point is fill it out with reasonable default values (whether that involves doing POSTs or PUTs is rather immaterial to the RESTfulness of the overall design), so the user can then take their time to alter the things that they want to look like they want them to.

The question then becomes one of whether there should be some kind of “release this; I'm done with altering it” operation at the end. Strict RESTfulness says there shouldn't, as if you know the resource identifier (the URL) then you can talk about it. On the other hand, that doesn't mean the hosting server has to tell *anyone else* about the resource until the creating user is happy with it; general HATEOAS principles say nothing about when others can discover that a resource exists or whether knowing the name lets you read the thing, but it's entirely reasonable to deny to third parties that a resource exists until the owner of the resource turns on the “make this public” flag.